# Why won't function return until background process ends?

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process, command-substitution

Consider this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
function start {
  leafpad &
  echo $!
}
PID=$(start)
echo "PID is $PID"
```

The script does not continue past its closing brace until the leafpad process ends, even though it is a background process.

Why is this? Is it possible to launch a background process from a function?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The function returns, but the command substitution blocks, because you created a background job, but you still have your stdout fd opened. Just close it by adding `>/dev/null` before the `&`.

```
#!/bin/bash
function start {
  leafpad >/dev/null &
  echo $!
}
PID=$(start)
echo "PID is $PID"
```

If you want your process to have also stdin, stdout, stderr closed, use this :

```
leafpad >/dev/null 0>&1 2>&1 &
```

This will close stdin (0), stdout (1), and stderr (2), then background (&).
Also, when using these [stream redirections](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) don't forget they are "duped", that means duplicated in the order of execution.

```
1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

and

```
2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

are not the same ! In the former, you are duplicating a stream to /dev/null (which is what you want), in the latter, you are duplicating /dev/stdout to stderr, and then, closing stdout. So any message sent to `stderr` will appear in your console.

Comment: Confirmed on my system

Comment: You're not closing the streams, you're redirecting them.

Comment: @dcat - true. They amount to much the same in `bash`. A `zsh` user might not notice any effect at all...

Comment: to close; `n>&-` where `n` is the file descriptor.

Comment: @dcat: Yes, but redirection to / from `/dev/null` won't lead to i/o errors when a process tries to write its stdout, but finds that `1` is an invalid FD.  So the terminology in the post is wrong, not the actual bash programming.  (Actually, duplicating FD 1 to 0 means that stdin will be a file-descriptor opened with `O_RDONLY`, which will probably give an error (rather than the desired no-bytes-available) when the process tries to read.)  e.g. `wc >/dev/null 0>&1` -> `wc: standard input: Bad file descriptor`

Comment: @PeterCordes - Closing the old descriptor and redirecting the new one need not be mutually exclusive. `exec <&- >&- <>/dev/null >&0` handles stdin/out pretty exhaustively. It makes a difference in `zsh` at least which will sort of concatenate all opens on the same descriptor automatically when multios is set.

Comment: @PeterCordes; yes, my reference was to the terminology, not its use.